# Elsarticle frontmatter corresponding author

Tags: titles, elsarticle, front-matter

I believe I have followed the template exactly but as this following MWE shows I am getting an asterisk on both authors and not just the corresponding author. Do I have something in the wrong order somewhere?

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title}

\author{Author One\corref{cor1}\fnref{fn1}}
\ead{email@uni.edu}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\fntext[fn1]{Student}

\author{Author Two\fnref{fn2}}
\ead{email2@uni.edu}
\fntext[fn2]{Lecturer}

\address{Address Here}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract abstract abstract
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Section1}
Start typing...

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I get only one asterisk for the first author. If your MWE really shows asterisks for both authors, then maybe your `elsarticle` template is too old. I used version 1.20b.

Comment: I got elsarticle 2009/09/17, 1.2.0: Elsevier Ltd and it shows the described bug. Interestingly everything is fine, if only the second author is marked as corresponding author. It helps as well to move the info from the `\fntext` to `\adress` .. strange bug indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Even downloading the latest elsarticle (v1.21) from RVT I still get the same problem. I will resort to using the fix below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a bug in the 2009 version, which is the one in the 2012 TeXlive.  When no address label is specified the correspondng `\@author` command forgets to reset the `\@corref` variable.  You can fix this by adding in such a reset as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\makeatletter
\def\@author#1{\g@addto@macro\elsauthors{\normalsize%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \upshape\authorsep#1\unskip\textsuperscript{%
      \ifx\@fnmark\@empty\else\unskip\sep\@fnmark\let\sep=,\fi
      \ifx\@corref\@empty\else\unskip\sep\@corref\let\sep=,\fi
      }%
    \def\authorsep{\unskip,\space}%
    \global\let\@fnmark\@empty
    \global\let\@corref\@empty  %% Added
    \global\let\sep\@empty}%
    \@eadauthor={#1}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title}

\author{Author One\corref{cor1}\fnref{fn1}}
\ead{email@uni.edu}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\fntext[fn1]{Student}


\author{Author Two\fnref{fn2}}
\ead{email2@uni.edu}
\fntext[fn2]{Lecturer}

\address{Address Here}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract abstract abstract
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Section1}
Start typing...

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just had the same problem. This Q&A site is (nearly) perfect!!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Just add a \corrref to every author (with different labels) and just call the author you need.

```
    \author{J.~Martinez}
    \author{F.~Julio\corref{cor1}}
    \ead{007@gmail.com}
    \author{N.~Vasquez\corref{cor2}}
    \author{H.~Cardenas\corref{cor2}}
    \cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
```

Comment: This may answer the question, but a full document would be more explanatory, as well as a screenshot

Comment: This solution works as well.

Comment: This is, in fact, the *optimal* answer. For sure, it's the method I use for my own submissions to Elsevier journals!

Answer (score 2):

Or more simply just download the newest elsarticle.cls from Elsevier ([here](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/text_file/0005/56903/elsarticle.cls)) and explicitly reference it at the beginning of the doc, *ala*

```
\documentclass[review]{./style/elsarticle}
```

Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Or more simply than what? Using the fix given in the accepted answer?

Comment: Yup. Why fix something when just using the correct version works?

Comment: @BarneyC - The main (only?!) reason for using the `elsarticle` document class is to prepare a paper for submission to an Elsevier journal.  When submitting a paper that uses the `elsarticle` document class, you will almost certainly be strongly discouraged from submitting a non-standard version of the document class file. By now, it's late 2017, and the official version of `elsarticle.cls`, i.e., the one that's on the CTAN and is distributed with TeXLive and MiKTeX, is still the buggy one. Sigh.