# Turn off superscript when all authors have same affiliation (elsarticle)

Tags: titles, elsarticle

I'm using the `elsarticle` class, which adds superscripts to link the author to their affiliation. However, all of the authors for my paper have the same affiliation, so it looks a little weird for them all to have the superscript "a" (as shown below).

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\author[su]{Jane Doe\corref{cor1}}
\ead{jdoe@someuniversity}
\author[su]{Joe Bloggs}
\ead{jbloggs@someuniversity}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\address[su]{Department of Underwater Basket-weaving, Some University}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to turn this off? I experimented with leaving off the `[su]` tags, but that results in all the authors getting an asterisk marking them as corresponding authors!

EDIT: Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\journal{Some Journal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{My Article}

\author[su]{Jane Doe\corref{cor1}}
\ead{jdoe@someuniversity}
\author[su]{Joe Bloggs}
\ead{jbloggs@someuniversity}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\address[su]{Department of Underwater Basket-weaving, Some University}

\begin{abstract}

Abstract

\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
test
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

Blah blah blah

\end{document}
\endinput
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve your output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\author{Jane Doe\corref{cor1}}
\ead{jdoe@someuniversity}
\author{Joe Bloggs\corref{}}
\ead{jbloggs@someuniversity}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\address{Department of Underwater Basket-weaving, Some University}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Providing an empty `\corref{}` to the non-corresponding author removes the unwanted asterisk.

Answer (score 4):

As you have found, `elsarticle` provides two ways of adding the authors - with and without a label (pages 4 and 5 of [the documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle)). If the label is omitted, then the authors before the `\address` will have the same affiliation. The asterisk denotes the corresponding author. Its repetition is a [known bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116537/89497) which may be fixed with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[preprint,10pt,3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\@author}{\global\let\@fnmark\@empty}{\global\let\@fnmark\@empty\global\let\@corref\@empty}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to patch \string\@author for \string\@corref reset}}
\makeatother

\journal{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title of my paper \tnoteref{label1}}
\tnotetext[label1]{A note to the title}

\author{Jane Doe\corref{cor1}}
\ead{jdoe@someuniversity}
\author{Joe Bloggs}
\ead{jbloggs@someuniversity}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\address{Department of Underwater Basket-weaving, Some University}

\begin{abstract}
  Abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
keyword1, keyword2
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]