# How to avoid adding the asterisk to the last author in elsarticle.cls?

Tags: elsarticle, author

My article has two authors. The first one is the only corresponding author. Hence my LaTeX code for the authors is:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\journal{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title}
\author{AuthorOne\corref{TheOnlyCorrespondingAuthor}}
\ead{authorone@gmail.com}
\author{AuthorTwo}
\ead{authortwo@gmail.com}
\cortext[TheOnlyCorrespondingAuthor]{Corresponding author}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

However, as the above clips show, LaTeX automatically adds the asterisk to the last author. Why?

Can anyone solve the problem?

You'd better not to change the based setting in the original elsarticle.cls LaTeX template.

Comment: In particular, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/259278/5001).